# Unable to disable ctrl+shift+u Unicode input shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, ibus, unicode

I am trying to disable the unicode insert keyboard shortcut of `ctrl+shift+u` but no matter what I do it is still enabled and I don't understand why. I want to disable it because it interferes with various shortcuts from other programs I use.

What I have tried (restarting my machine after each one):

1. Removing the shortcut in `ibus-setup`.
2. Reassigning the shortcut in `ibus-setup` to something else.
3. Removing the shortcut via dconf editor.
4. Forcing my language to **not** us ibus in the the language settings.
5. Purging all ibus related packages.

After each step the `ctrl+shift+u` keyboard shortcut works in all apps. This leads me to think perhaps it is assigned by something else? But I can't figure out what is causing this behaviour and it doesn't seem configurable.

Most of the other posts I have read about this seem to end with a combination of ibus changes. However none of these work for me.

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Gnome 42.5
Wayland

Comment: Related bug report: https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2512

Comment: well, is it possible at all???

Comment: Unfortunately no. The relevant gnome bug maintainer has basically told everyone to get stuffed and isn't going to allow customisation. His reasoning vague and illogical. So, no, this isn't possible.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/5865