Ubuntu 22 - how to find what intercepts keyboard shortcut
Recently I found out, that something globally intercepts keyboard shortcut ctrl+shift+U.
In most text edit apps, this shortcut is used to toggle upper/lower case. But now, no matter where I use this shortcut, it just inserts underscored "u" as symbol for some special character.
I've checked settings->keyboard->keyboard shortcuts and no action has this shortcut.
As I said this shortcut works everywhere, overriding this shortcut in all apps, so it looks like system related setting.
Is there anyway to check where it is assigned, to what, and remove it? I use this shortcut a lot in InteliJ and Notepad++, and it gets me furious when I cannot use it.
Already replying to answers "reinstall system": installing and configuring whole environment I use for work will take a week, that is not accaptable.

CTRL+Shift+U is used globally to insert unicode sequences, I think you'll have to change your editor's keybindings.

https://askubuntu.com/q/1457596/380067

And https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/5865

When this feature for unicode was added? This shortcut was working for toggling upper/lower case, at least in intelij and notepad++, as I was using it before

My understanding is that this is a feature of GTK, so it makes sense that applications not based on GTK won't exhibit this behavior... But for app based on GTK I think you're out of luck, many app offer GUIs based on other libraries such as QT, you may try and look for an alternate GUI for the apps you're using

Sometime ago I had a similar problem on a Debian KDE distro: I discovered after a long investigqation that the keyboard layout was changed (from the standard Italian to Frenchetc.)check that something similar is not happening to you as well!
